# .htaccess replace the %23 on # hash?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

*Hi, I need help with .htaccess

For two days I can not understand how it works, that only have not tried it.
By default there has been:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [NC]
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

There is a link:

http://domain.ru/s_shoping/shop?sid=253%23modal/bundle/82522
The link is: 23%, need to replace (#) hash.

These links appear when the share of Skype on the ios, in other programs have the same problem

I tried write in different ways:

```
RewriteRule ^(/shop\?sid=[0-9]*)?%23(modal/bundle/[0-9]*)$ /shop\?    sid=$1#modal/bundle/$2 [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?%23(.*)?$ $1#$2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

In general, I tried a lot of of options with different flags, additional modules, etc. but all is useless ...

What I make mistakes? If you use one group, everything works, if two, then breaks down
Nothing special in the regular season of not ...
Who can help, what am I doing wrong

Comment: I am so confused... So, are you trying to replace "sid=253%23modal" with hash? Or specifically the 253?

Comment: Only %23 on #, and all

Comment: What is "all" and what is on #?

http://domain.ru/s_shoping/shop?sid=253%23modal/bundle/82522

Tell me what you want this link to look like.

Comment: [link](domain.com/s_shoping/shop?sid=253%23modal/bundle/85667)  on [link](domain.com/s_shoping/shop?sid=253#modal/bundle/85667)